# Calculate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {2e^{-1/x^2}}{x^3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Got this question and was wondering why the limit is $0$ ?
I saw a few people that mentioned that it can be written when $\frac {2e^{-1/x^2}}{x^3}$ and such limits is always $0$.

Is there any way to explain it or to show it specifically somehow ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $te^{-t}\to0$ as $t\to\infty$. Put $t=1/x^2$.

Comment: Just use L'Hopital.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that for $t>0$ you have $e^t = 1+ t +\frac{t^2}{2} +\cdots > \frac{t^2}{2}$.

Hence,

\begin{eqnarray*} \left| \frac {2e^ \frac {-1}{x^2}}{x^3} \right|
& = & \frac 2{e^\frac 1{x^2}\cdot |x|^3} \\
& < & \frac 2{\frac 1{2x^4}\cdot |x|^3} \\
& = & 4|x| \stackrel{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow} 0
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2 e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x^3};\;x=\frac{1}{t}$$

we have
$$\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{2 e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x^3}=\underset{t\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{2 t^3}{e^{t^2}}=\underset{t\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{6 t^2}{2 te^{t^2} }=\underset{t\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{3t}{e^{t^2}}=\underset{t\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{3}{2te^{t^2}}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

You have that $$\frac{2}{x^3e^{1/x^2}}=\frac{2}{x^3\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac12\frac{1}{x^4}+\cdots\right)}=\frac{2}{x^3+x+\frac12 \frac 1x+\cdots},$$ so that as $x\to 0,$ we see that the term in $1/x$ and the higher terms go to $\infty,$ so that the quotient goes to $0.$